# No Such Element Exception for my babyname function

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

This my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BabyNames
{
    public static int decades = 11;
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {      
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(550,560);        
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        String line = search();
        graph(g,line);
    }   

    public static String search() throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner util = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));     
        String line = "";
        String requestedName = name();
        String rankings = "";
        String rank = "";

        while (util.hasNextLine())
        {       
            line = util.nextLine();
            Scanner tracer = new Scanner(line);
            String name = tracer.next();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(requestedName))
            {
                for (int x =1;x<=decades;x++)
                {
                    rank = tracer.next();
                    rankings+=rank+" ";
                }
            } 
            if (!util.hasNextLine())
            {
                System.out.print("no data");
                break;               
            }
        }        
        return rankings;
    }

    public static String name()
    {
        String requestName = "";
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a name: ");
        requestName = console.next();
        return requestName;
    }

    public static void graph(Graphics g,String rankings)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0,0,550,30);
        g.fillRect(0,530,550,30);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        for (int x = 0; x <= 11;x++)
        {
            g.drawLine(0+50*x,30,0+50*x,530);
        }

        for (int x = 0;x<=10;x++)
        {
            g.drawLine(0,30+50*x,550,30+50*x);
        }

        Scanner console = new Scanner(rankings);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        int position = 0;
        int firstRank = console.nextInt();
        int position2 = firstRank/2+30;

        for (int x = 0; x<=decades-1;x++)
        {
            int rank = console.nextInt();
            if (rank==0)
            {
                position=530;
            } 
            else 
            {
                position = rank/2+30;
            }
            g.drawLine(0+x*50-50,position2,0+x*50,position);
            position2 = position;
        }
    }

}
```

The code asks for a name, then it searches for that name in the file, and then graphs the rankings in another window.

The file is formatted like this:

[image]

It gives me a no such element exception when I run my code.

Complete error message:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException at
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862) at 
java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) at 
BabyNames.graph(BabyNames.java:75) at 
BabyNames.main(BabyNames.java:13)
```

Comment: You should pin point the error and ask specifics.  As it stands, we have to figure out what you are doing, by reading your code.  See [mcve].  You have more details than *"no such element exception"* ?  What debugging did you do?  Edit the title, you have no babyname function in the code presented.  Only a BabyNames class.

Comment: Sorry, I have located that the error occurs in the graph function. Babynames is just the name of the assignment. 
I tried changing the for loop to modify the amount of times it looks for another int but that didnt seem to help. I also changed the for loop into a while(tracer.hasNext && x<decades-1) but that didnt' work

Comment: You are not checking hasNext on tracer. Any line in your file which is not correctly formatted will cause an exception

Comment: The error says java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at BabyNames.graph(BabyNames.java:75)
 at BabyNames.main(BabyNames.java:13)

Comment: Dale should I replace the for loop with a while(tracer.hasNext && x<decades-1)?

Comment: I put your error message in the question (you can edit your question, don't put code or stacks in comments).  Could you please identify lines 75 and 13 from your posted code?

Comment: thanks for the help I kept changing my code and found something that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

1. As user to enter a name
2. Look at given file and find a line that starts with given name and returns it's rankings
3. Show this rankings on UI

In 2nd you do:

1. Find a string with given name
2. Read all integers separately and build a string with it (why not just read a whole string from file)
3. Retrieve this string back to caller.

In 3rd you do:

1. Accept given string
2. Split this string into separate integers (again, why not accept `List<Integer>` instead of `String[] {1, 2, 3}`)
3. Show integers on UI

Do not forget to **close** `Scanner` after usage, it could flow a problem.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> rankings = getRankings(Paths.get("d:/names.txt"));
}

public static List<Integer> getRankings(Path path) throws IOException {
    return getNameRankings(getName(), path);
}

private static String getName() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Type a name: ");
        return scan.next();
    }
}

private static List<Integer> getNameRankings(String name, Path path) throws IOException {
    String[] data = Files.lines(path)
                         .map(String::trim)
                         .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
                         .filter(parts -> parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(null);

    if (data == null)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    return IntStream.range(1, data.length)
                    .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(data[i]))
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```